# Where do you put your Procfile in JAR deployments?

Tags: heroku

I just can't figure out where to put it. I tried `src/main/resources/`, and that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Put it in the root directory of your project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location):

> The Procfile must live in your app’s root directory. It does not function if placed anywhere else.

That's where Heroku looks for all of its configuration files.